# Azure Function Request Tracing

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-application-insights

I have enabled Application Insights in my Azure Functions app and can now track the function invocations. However, many functions invoke other functions and I would like to see the entire function invocation for a request. In Application Insights I found request ids and invocation ids but did not find how the correlate.

Is this possible or do I need to build this myself?

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, app Insights doesn't contain the Dependency tracking between the azure function and azure function. So it will not auto correlate the two azure functions.

If you want to correlate two azure function, I suggest you could write your own logic to enable Dependency tracking between the azure function and azure function.

You should firstly install the Microsoft.ApplicationInsights package in the azure function.

Upload the package.json file to the azure function folder.

details:

```
{
  "frameworks": {
    "net46":{
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights": "2.2.0"
      }
    }
   }
}
```

Then you could use [TelemetryClient.TrackDependency](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.applicationinsights.telemetryclient.trackdependency?view=appinsights-2.3.0-beta3) to enable the Dependency tracking.

More details, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-asp-net-dependencies#custom-dependency-tracking).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're wanting 'correlation' across separate function invocations. That is not currently supported, but we're looking into ways to enable this -- it's tracked here: https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/245

Comment: Thanks, we'll watch the issue